# Hadoop Definitive Guide "National Climatic Data Center" get the data

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to learn Hadoop. I'm trying to get the `National Climatic Data Center` data to my newly installed Hadoop  Master. What is the easiest way of getting whole data

Edit: since I get down vote even I get my answer I think I should explain my question in detail. On download Page there are many files in .gz format. And I need to get those files in a human friendly way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you find the site and you see data. I hope that's why you ask this question. you need to install wget with a package manager like  `sudo apt-get install wget` then use wget tool appropriate parameters. For one degree and .gz file use

`wget -r -np -l 1 -A gz http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/orders/qclcd/`

Comment: actually I was asking wget parameters sorry for my weak English and thank you  for your answer.